# {emailcloak=off} any way to do this programmatically?

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, joomla-api

I'm writing a plugin, and the auto-email cloaking functionality is breaking my output. For example: I'll write some output:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$var={ "content" : "text with embedded@address.domain"}
</script>
```

The address cloaker is treating $var as HTML content and just making a mess out of it.

I've found that I can disable that by putting {emailcloak=off} in the article. The issue is that I'm writing a commercial plugin. I don't want to depend upon end-users to remember to do that anywhere they use my shortcode.

Is there a way that I can turn Email cloaking off from inside my plugin for just my content?

Comment: I guess you already know you can disable cloaking via the core plugin Content - Email Cloaking...

Comment: See also [this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21331719/2780063).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He will distribute it. So he is trying to  find a workaround inside the plugin.

One solution could be to encrypt the email in base64  on php side and decode it on javascript with

```
Base64.decode(emailEncodedonPHPSide)
```

By using this, the email cloaker will not detect it as an email